# TortoiseSVN Commit failed: MERGE failed

Tags: svn, github, merge, tortoisesvn, tortoisemerge

I'm having troubles to commit any change after merging on pull-request from github respository.
I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.7.11, Build 23600 - 64 Bit , 2012/12/12 19:08:52
Subversion 1.7.8,

The error I'm getting when trying to commit the changes (or any minor change) is:

> Error - Commit failed (details follow):
>
> Error - MERGE failed

[image]

I've tried to use the `clean up` option over the main project directory, then `SVN Update` over the same folder and finally using the `SVN Commit...` action and still having the same exact issue.

I'm using the last downloaded revision of my project and I'm just trying to add a number to a line. As you can see, the changes I'm trying to commit are minimum.

I've also tried to resolve the merge conflicts manually but still getting the same error when commiting.

I even tried to download the repository again in another folder on my computer, then adding this number in a line and then commiting and stil having the error.

Any idea about how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I have exact same problem which started happening today with svn commit at github repositories, I have multiple repositories at github and it fails with "MERGE failed" in ALL of them! (I'm using the  latest svn: 1.8.5)
It seems this problem is specific to github and apparently only they can fix it from their side.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Hopefully they will fix it soon...

Comment: I had the same just now, I mailed Github about it. Will post updates here.

Comment: Update: It seems github fixed the problem, I was able to commit just now without any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a temporary problem at Github. They reported it as fixed two hours ago. Tested it, works for me again.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if your file is bigger than 100 MB.